# Is there support for geo uri in latex?

Tags: urls, hyperlink

Is geo uri supported in latex? are there any packages that support geo uri?

Ideally, I want to be able to do this:

```
{\href{geo:37.786971,-122.399677;u=35}{Home}}
```

When user clicks on the link default map app opens. just like mailto:

Regards

Comment: [Also posted on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65807559).

Answer (score 1):

Open as a link in what?

How about:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

  \href{https://www.google.com/maps/place/37%C2%B047'13.1%22N+122%C2%B023'58.8%22W/@37.786971,-122.4018657,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d37.786971!4d-122.399677}{The place}
\end{document}
```

There is a geo URI scheme defined by RFC 5870 of the form
geo:124.028582,-29.201930
But I think imagining that this will open something sensible every place you might load a pdf is wishful thinking. I'd imagine whether such a link would go anywhere at all even if it could be implemented would depend not only on the browser or PDF reader, but also on the underlying OS.